# Converting date and/or time from character string is failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query and I tried converting it to every format, I mean the date time etc but it doesn't work and throws error:

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

```
SELECT  W.Organization_ID, 
        W.NIT_No, 
        W.SchemeID,
        OpeningDate,
        OpeningTime,
        GETDATE(), 
        WorkNo, 
        CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), W.Cost) AS Cost, 
        WorkName, 
        W.ExpiryDate as ExpiryDate,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,OpeningDate,106),
        CASE WHEN 
               CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),OpeningDate,106) + ' ' 
               + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),OpeningTime,108))< GETDATE() 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END AS OpeningVaild
FROM Works W
```

the `CASE` part throws error.

> OpeningDate is of type Varchar and OpeningTime is of type Time.

Why?

Comment: You should _Always_ specify the length of `VARCHAR`

Comment: 100 is the size. Varchar(100)

Comment: Well, I don't see 100 here `CONVERT(VARCHAR,OpeningDate,106),`

Comment: I did. that doesn't work

Comment: I changed styles too

Comment: What's the format of the sting representation of the date value you keep in `OpeningDate`, and why are you storing dates as `varchar` to begin with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: this is the format of openingdate 2017-04-10

Comment: `10` being the day or month here?

Comment: "*OpeningDate is of type Varchar... Why?"* This is a good question, why is `OpeningDate` a `varchar` when it should be the data type `date`. We can't answer that, as we didn't design your system, however, I strongly suggest it's been designed poorly if it is storing dates as a `varchar`; especially one that allow 100 characters (dates normally only consist of about 10 characters (yyyy-MM-dd)).

Answer (score 0):

You are converting just a `TIME` datatype not a `DATETIME` so you don't need to specify the style:

```
DECLARE @T TIME = '08:05:06';

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @T) AS [Time];
SELECT CAST(@T AS VARCHAR(8)) AS [Time];
```

Or since you are using `CONVERT()`pick the right [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) for `TIME` datatype which is `108` or `114`,  instead of `106`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @T, 108) AS [Time];
```

---

Update:

According to the error Msg, your problem is in the `CASE` part.

That because you are trying to concat a `DATETIME` with a `VARCHAR` datatype, look at here to what you'r converting:

```
CASE WHEN 
       CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),OpeningDate,106) + ' ' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),OpeningTime,108))< GETDATE() 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 END AS OpeningVaild
```

Also the column `OpeningDate` -*according to the error Msg*- is `VARCHAR` so your are convert a `VARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` then convert it again to `DATETIME` then you try to concatinate the `DATETIME` with the `VARCHAR` returned from converting `OpeningTime` column from `TIME`to `VARCHAR`, then try to compare them with `GETDATE()` which is `DATETIME` datatype.

So you `CASE` should look like:

```
CASE WHEN 
       (
         CAST(OpeningDate AS DATETIME) + -- VARCHAR to DATETIME  
         CAST(OpeningTime AS DATETIME)   -- TIME to DATETIME
       ) < GETDATE() 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 END AS OpeningVaild
```

A beside note, here in this line

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,OpeningDate,106),
```

You are trying to convert a `VARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` and without specify the lenght too, so this line should be:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(OpeningDate AS DATE),106),
```

Finally, don't ever ever store `DATE` as `VARCHAR`, the `DATE/ TIME/ DATEIME` are there for a reason, so use them and all other datatypes wisely.

Here is a **[demo](https://rextester.com/SIOF23185)** represent your issue, and how to fix it.

Comment: @PostingQuestions Remove your case stmt, and replace it with the last one in my answer and try

Comment: @PostingQuestions If this doesn't fix the problem, please consider to add DDL, Sample Data, Expected Results as `formatted text` not images.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand the problem is with this part:

> `CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),OpeningDate,106) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),OpeningTime,108))< GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OpeningVaild`

### Update

Since I've first posted my answer it turns out that you store the opening date as `varchar` instead of `date`.
First, you should stop doing that. Never store dates in anything other than a `Date` column (unless you need them with time as well, and then use `DateTime2`).
For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Assuming the data type of the column can't change, you wrote in the comments to the question:

> @ZoharPeled: this is the format of openingdate 2017-04-10

Illustrating one of the problems caused by storing dates as strings - How can I, or anyone else for that matter, know if that's the 10th of April or the 4th of October? The answer is we can't.

So, assuming it's the 10th of April, you can convert it to `DateTime` using convert with 126 as the style parameter:

```
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(DateTime, OpeningDate, 126) + CAST(OpeningTime As DateTime) < GETDATE() THEN 
        1 
    ELSE 
        0 
END As OpeningVaild
```

### First version:

Assuming that the data type of `OpeningDate` is `Date` and the data type of `OpeningTime` is `Time`, Seems like you are attempting to figure out if these columns combination into a `DateTime` is before the current `DateTime`.

Instead of converting them into strings and back to `DateTime`, you can cast both to `DateTime` and simply add them together:

```
CASE 
    WHEN CAST(OpeningDate As DateTime) + CAST(OpeningTime As DateTime) < GETDATE() THEN 
        1 
    ELSE 
        0 
END As OpeningVaild
```

Another option would be to use `GETDATE()` twice. I don't think it should matter in the `select` clause, but in the `where` clause it's important to use this option since the first one will make these columns non-seargable, meaning the database engine will not be able to use any indexes that might help the execution plan of the statement:

```
CASE 
WHEN OpeningDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
     OR 
     (
         OpeningDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
         AND OpeningTime <= CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)
     ) THEN 
    1 
ELSE 
    0 
END AS OpeningVaild
```

That being said, your query also have `CONVERT(VARCHAR,OpeningDate,106)` - The 106 style returns a string representation of the date as `dd mon yyyy` - meaning 11 chars - so change that to `CONVERT(CHAR(11),OpeningDate,106)` Note that using `varchar` without specifying the length defaults to 30, which is not a problem in this case since it's more than he 11 chars you need, but [it's a bad habit to not specify length and you should kick it.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: *OpeningDate is of type Varchar* That information was not in the question when I've written my answer. Editing it now to handle that.

Comment: Well, I can't really answer until you answer the comment I've left on the question. Please do.

Comment: OpeningDate is varchar(100)

Comment: date is stored like 2017-04-10

Comment: @PostingQuestion perhaps it's time you posted some sample data. And also, it's far past time to fix your data types. A date isn't a `varchar`, it's a `date`. Why aren't you storing it as one? There's is almost never a good reason.

Comment: Your logic in the last example is incorrect. Imagine getdate is 2018-10-15 00:15 and the data is 2018-10-14 00:16. Openingtime is higher than time of getdate - although the date is lower. Giving wrong answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Good catch! Thanks! fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this big time by changing the expression a little.

This way you don't have to convert and concatenate.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN OpeningDate < GETDATE() - OpeningTime
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 END AS OpeningVaild
```

Note I am assuming that Openingdate has the format dd-mon-yyyy. Otherwise you still need to convert it, but still shorter:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Convert(date, OpeningDate, 106) < GETDATE() - OpeningTime
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 END AS OpeningVaild
```